# numba does not accept numpy arrays with dtype=object

Tags: python, arrays, numba

I have an empty array that I want to fill with arbitrary length lists at each index [i,j]. So I initialize an empty array that is supposed to hold objects like this:

```
@jit(nopython=True, parrallel=True)
def numba_function():
    values          = np.empty((length, length), dtype=object)
    for i in range(10):
        for j in range(10):
            a_list_of_things = [1,2,3,4]
            values[i,j] = a_list_of_things
```

This fails with:

```
 TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend) Untyped global name 'object': cannot determine Numba type of <class 'type'>
```

If I turn off numba by setting `nopython=False` the code works fine. Setting `dtype=list` in the `values` array does not improve things.

Any smart tricks to overcome this?

Comment: HI @TrebledJ, yes of course thats a typo in my post. I've now added the @ in my mwe! (without it there is undefined variable njit...)

Comment: (and i'm actually using `@jit` not `@njit` in my code, updated!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numba in nopython mode (as of version 0.43.1) does not support object arrays.

The correct way to type an object array would be:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def numba_function():
    values = np.empty((2, 2), np.object_)
    return values
```

But as stated, that doesn't work:

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Internal error at resolving type of attribute "object_" of "$0.4":
NotImplementedError: object
```

This is also mentioned in [the numba documentation](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.43.0/reference/numpysupported.html#scalar-types):

> ## 2.7.1. Scalar types
>
> Numba supports the following Numpy scalar types:
>
> - Integers: all integers of either signedness, and any width up to 64 bits
> - Booleans
> - Real numbers: single-precision (32-bit) and double-precision (64-bit) reals
> - Complex numbers: single-precision (2x32-bit) and double-precision (2x64-bit) complex numbers
> - Datetimes and timestamps: of any unit
> - Character sequences (but no operations are available on them)
> - Structured scalars: structured scalars made of any of the types above and arrays of the types above
>
> **The following scalar types and features are not supported:**
>
> - **Arbitrary Python objects**
> - Half-precision and extended-precision real and complex numbers
> - Nested structured scalars the fields of structured scalars may not contain other structured scalars
>
> [...]
>
> ## 2.7.2. Array types
>
> Numpy arrays of any of the scalar types above are supported, regardless of the shape or layout.

(Emphasis mine)

Since `dtype=object` would allow arbitrary Python objects it's not supported. And `dtype=list` is just equivalent to `dtype=object` ([documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html#specifying-and-constructing-data-types))

> ## Built-in Python types
>
> Several python types are equivalent to a corresponding array scalar when used to generate a dtype object:
>
> ```
> int           np.int_
> bool          np.bool_
> float         np.float_
> complex       np.cfloat
> bytes         np.bytes_
> str           np.bytes_ (Python2) or np.unicode_ (Python3)
> unicode       np.unicode_
> buffer        np.void
> (all others)  np.object_
> ```

---

All that said: It would be quite slow to have `object` arrays, that applies to NumPy arrays and numba functions. Whenever you choose to use such `object` arrays you *implicitly* decide that you don't want high-performance.

So if you want performance and use NumPy arrays, then you need to rewrite it so you don't use object arrays first and if it's still to slow, then you can think about throwing numba at the non-object arrays.

Comment: Thanks for explaining... Could you point to reading starting point how an efficient implementation for a "store an arbitrary length result at a given index" type problem looks like?

Comment: @Sebastiano1991 In my experience NumPy isn't a good fit for "ragged data structures". The solution depends a lot on the kind of problem you're trying to solve, there's no perfect general solution. In most cases Python lists are already fast enough (which can be ragged). But as stated that depends on what problem you have, if "heavy number crunching" is involved and other factors, i.e. is setup the bottleneck or the operations, what operations, is it really arbitrary length or are there constraints.

Comment: However that exceeds what can and should be discussed in the comments, if you're looking for help with your actual problem you should ask a new question including the requirements and optimally a working approach that you consider too inefficient.